# How do I extract the key of an element which has been comma delimited?

Tags: xml, xslt

The XML...

```
<BaseElement>
     <AttributeList
     >ThreadId=1,ThreadName=Foo,ApplicationName=Bar</AttributeList>
</BaseElement>
```

I'm trying to extract the value within `ThreadId`...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="AttributesList"/>
```

The above displays the entire list; `ThreadId=1,ThreadName=Foo, ...`

Looked into substring but that appears fairly fixed in nature. It needs to dynamic so that if the the *key*, which in this case would be `ThreadId` changes to `NewFangledThreadId` it continues to function.

Comment: You need to compose some function into a tokenizer template. The same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372319/xsl-if-help-needed-please

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is fully parameterized and generic. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation is fully parameterized and generic**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:param name="pAttrName" select="'AttributeList'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pKeyName" select="'ThreadId'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring-before(
           substring-after(concat(',',
                                   /*/*[name()=$pAttrName],
                                   ','
                                  ),
                            concat(',', $pKeyName, '=')
                            ),
                     ','
                     )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<BaseElement>
    <AttributeList
    >ThreadId=1,ThreadName=Foo,ApplicationName=Bar</AttributeList>
</BaseElement>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
1
```

**When we just specify**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pKeyName" select="'ApplicationName'"/>
```

**again the correct result is produced**:

```
Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="AttributeList">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '='), ',')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
1
```

It selects the portion of the string that comes after the first `=` and before the first `,`.

Comment: I need to match against the BaseElement, not AttributeList; where AttributeList resides within the BaseElement.

Comment: That's fine. You can match anywhere you want. The important point of my answer is how to extract the wanted text: `substring-before(substring-after(., '='), ',')`

Comment: @Aaron - From inside a match of `BaseElement` change it to this: `substring-before(substring-after(AttributeList, '='), ',')`

Comment: +1 It works under the specified conditions however it also appears static in nature. ie...if I remove the trailing attributes and only have the ThreadId attribute I have to change the XSL. Is there no way to address the value by index?

Comment: @Aaron - The general case you describe is best handled by some sort of tokenizer. See @Alejandro's link in the question's comments.